# Custom Text in jQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have to display date in input box after picking from datepicker using jQuery.
I have used following code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: -0,
        maxDate: "+1M +2D",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: 'D dd MM' });
    $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd');
});
```

And I am able to get date in this format: "Fri 09 August".
However my requirement is: Fri 09 August (Today)

Here's a JS Fiddle to work upon: http://jsfiddle.net/4cgPe/

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find much about adding custom text to jQuery, so I came up with my own JavaScript.
I built upon your DatePicker code.

(What I understood was, if the selected date is of today, then add " (Today)", OR, add " (Tomorrow)" if selected date is of tomorrow OR, add nothing for other dates.

```
<html><head><link type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: -0,
        maxDate: "+1M +2D",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: 'D dd MM yy' });
    $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd');
});

function updateDate(){
    var inputDate=document.getElementById('datepicker').value; 
    var selectedDate=new Date(inputDate);
    var today=new Date();
    var tomorrow=new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
    selectedDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    tomorrow.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var DaysFull=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
    var DaysShort=["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"];
    var MonthsFull=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January"];
    var MonthsShort=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jan"];
    var finalDate=DaysShort[selectedDate.getDay()]+" "+selectedDate.getDate()+" "+MonthsFull[selectedDate.getMonth()];
    if(selectedDate.getTime() == today.getTime()){

        document.getElementById('datepicker').value=finalDate+" (Today)";
    }
    else if(selectedDate.getTime() == tomorrow.getTime()){document.getElementById('datepicker').value=finalDate+" (Tomorrow)";}
    else {document.getElementById('datepicker').value=finalDate;}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form><input type="text" id="datepicker" onchange="javascript:updateDate()" /></form>
</body></html>
```

**EDIT:**

Additional Functionality: There may be a requirement to use Full Days/Months name or Short Days/Months, so you can use the array accordingly.

*DaysFull*: Sunday, Monday, etc.

*DaysHalf*: Sun, Mon, etc.

*MonthsFull*: January, February, etc.

*MonthsHalf*: Jan, Feb, etc.

Hope this helps. Let me know if this is not enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

Full Source Code as below for different types of format :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( "#format" ).change(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30" /></p>

<p>Format options:<br />
    <select id="format">
        <option value="mm/dd/yy">Default - mm/dd/yy</option>
        <option value="yy-mm-dd">ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd</option>
        <option value="d M, y">Short - d M, y</option>
        <option value="d MM, y">Medium - d MM, y</option>
        <option value="DD, d MM, yy">Full - DD, d MM, yy</option>
        <option value="'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy">With text - 'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy</option>
    </select>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

More about format refer [This link](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: I want to add "today" or "tomorrow" to my date. I am already getting another info which youur code is intended to do so..